# Calculations on vectors become slower after better optimization flag and OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp, compiler-optimization

Consider the following Fortran code

```
program example
    implicit none
    integer, parameter  ::  ik = selected_int_kind(15)
    integer, parameter  ::  rk = selected_real_kind(15,307)

    integer(ik)         :: N, i, j, pc, time_rate, start_time, end_time, M

    real(rk), allocatable:: K(:,:), desc(:,:)
    real(rk)                :: kij, dij

    integer             :: omp_get_num_threads, nth
    N = 2000
    M = 400

    allocate(K(N,N))
    allocate(desc(N,M))

    pc=10
    do i = 1, N
        desc(i,:) = real(i,rk)
        if (i==int(N*pc)/100) then
            print * ,"desc % complete: ",pc
            pc=pc+10
        endif
    enddo
    call system_clock(start_time)
    !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(nth)
    nth = omp_get_num_threads()
    print *,"omp threads", nth
    !$OMP END PARALLEL

    !$OMP PARALLEL DO &
    !$OMP DEFAULT(SHARED) &
    !$OMP PRIVATE(i,j,dij,kij)
    do i = 1, N
        do j = i, N
            dij = sum(abs(desc(i,:) - desc(j,:)))
            kij = dexp(-dij)
            K(i,j) = kij
            K(j,i) = kij
        enddo
        K(i,i) = K(i,i) + 0.1
    enddo
    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO

    call system_clock(end_time, time_rate)
    print* , "Time taken for Matrix:", real(end_time - start_time, rk)/real(time_rate, rk)

end program example
```

I compiled it using gfortran-6 on MacOS X 10.11 usin following flags

1. `gfortran example.f90 -fopenmp -O0`
2. `gfortran example.f90 -fopenmp -O3`
3. `gfortran example.f90 -fopenmp -mtune=native`

following which I ran it with single and double threads using OMP_NUM_THREADS variable. I can see that it is utilizing two cores. However O3 flag which should enable vectorization, does not help the performance at all, if anything it degrades it a bit. Timings are given below (in seconds) (avgd over 10 runs):

```
|Thrds->|   1  |  2  |
|Opt    |      |     |
----------------------
|O0     |10.962|9.183|
|O3     |11.581|9.250|
|mtune  |11.211|9.084|
```

What is wrong in my program?

Comment: Are those 6 results in the table just from 6 run or have you averaged over a enough runs? You should definitely do the latter, and my feeling is that none of the 3 optimization levels has a better performance than the others, on the average. Maybe because the problem size is small? There's no communication between the threads, right? (Sorry, I've never used OpenMP, just MPI, and they are two completely different things...)

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, averaged over 3 runs. I am relatively new to omp as well. But i would assume given the fact that `sum` and `abs` operate on vectors, i would see considerable performance gain in O0 vs O3. I tried larger size as well, pattern is the same

Comment: I wouldn't say 3 is statistically relevant. And since the code is so simple to run, if I was you I would write a simple `bash` script to make the stats for you.

Comment: I am running currently average over 10, will update results once done

Comment: I suggested to write a script so you can make statistics for 100 at least.

Comment: Another tip.  Use "exp" instead of "dexp".  dexp is archaic.   For many, many years the language has specified that the compiler automatically select the correct intrinsic function according to the type of the argument.

Comment: Optimization flag wouldn't do much for performance unless it invokes a simd vector math library for exp. Parallel slowdown would be expected due to false sharing, threads updating the same cache line in K until you make N large enough to defeat the advantage of cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you want good performance from `-O3`, you should give it something that can actually be optimised. The bulk of the work happens in the `sum` intrinsic, which works on a vectorised expression. It doesn't get any more optimised when you switch from `-O0` to `-O3`.

Also, if you want better performance, transpose `desc` because `desc(i,:)` is non-contiguous in memory. `desc(:,i)` is. That's Fortran - its matrices are column-major.